# Cannot delete draft APKs from Play Developer Console v2: "Please check the form for errors"

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I'm new to android development, and have managed to get my v2 developer console in a bit of a state. There are multiple APKs (it's a game with multiple texture compression schemes for different devices). I've uploaded all the new APKs, and archived the old ones. I'm trying to upgrade from version *055 to *057.

There is a big wall of red text:

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
    It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 2009 to version 1057, which would occur when 
    API levels in range 8+ and 
    Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
    Native platforms containing any of [armeabi-v7a] and 
    OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
    OpenGL textures containing any of [GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc] and containing any of [GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture] but excluding all of [GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture, GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc] and 
    Features containing all of [android.hardware.sensor.ACCELEROMETER, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.touchscreen.MULTITOUCH, android.hardware.WIFI].
```

Hitting Reset Draft shows a red banner saying `The application could not be saved, please check the form for errors.` Hitting delete on any individual APK shows the same thing.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of help available for the new developer console, so I'm at a loss as to how to fix the wall of red text and why I can't delete or reset anything. Any pointers?

UPDATE:

It looks like I can publish from the old developer console, but I haven't tried it yet, and even if I can I will still hit this wall when they retire the old console.

I've dug out version 2009, and it supported S3TC textures as well as DXT*. It was over 10 revisions ago, well before my time and the previous develop has left (haven't they always?). 2009 is the last version that supported S3TC. Ever since, here's how my build numbers correspond to textures:

```
4***: GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc, GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
3***: GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
2***: GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt5
1***: GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
```

I'm using Unity 4 to make my APKs, so I don't think there's any scope for changing what build number corresponds to what texture compression.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here,  you can ask Google directly: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/136601?hl=en

Comment: add an answer anyway, my apk stays hidden, but can't be deleted either =(

Comment: I've tried posting on the android developers google group - msg never appeared. Maybe I was moderated? Contacted google using the form @Kevin linked to - no response yet. :-/

Comment: Have you altered your manifest in anyway? If so, what did you change?

Comment: Since version 2009 I don't know. Nothing in this version. But Unity handles the manifest anyway - I don't really have to touch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity v4.1.x seems to solve this: DXT option now exports dxt1 and s3tc. Yay!

Grr: it no longer supports DXT5, so I have the same problem, but with my previous version instead. I have to add DXT5 manually to the manifest, which sucks.